# Access a react child object key and value pair

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following code to return a list element with key and value pairs from an object passed in by the parent component using the props.  Why doesn't it work?

I get an error saying:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'props' of undefined(…) The error is because of the this.props.data call in my return statement.  It is not an issue with the data not being passed in through the props.  I looked through the react output tree and my data object is indeed passed in to the child.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
         <div>
           {this.props.transactions.map(function(el,i) {
             return <div key={i}>
                 <div>
                     {el.category}
                 </div>
                <Child data={el.months}/>
             </div>;
           })}
         </div>
      );
  }
}
class Child extends React.Component {
  render(){
    return (
      <ul>
      {Object.keys(this.props.data).map(function(key,index) {
           return <li key={index}>{this.props.data[key]}</li>
        })};
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

Here is the data passed in by the parent component:

```
[{
  "category": "Bills",
  "month": {
    "feb": 9,
    "mar": 169,
    "apr": 10,
    "may": 867,
    "jun": 394,
    "jul": 787,
    "aug": 1112,
    "sep": 232,
    "oct": 222,
    "nov": 306,
    "dec": 1096
  }
}];
```

Comment: Not what you ask about, but you should not use array index as key, especially not if the array may be reordered og items are added or removed. If `category` is unique, you can use that as key instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`this` inside the `map` function is referring to the **function** NOT the **react component's instance**, so you need to pass `this` explicitly as follow:

(1) *On the fly:*

```
{
  Object.keys(this.props.data).map(function(key,index) {
    return <li key={index}>{this.props.data[index]}</li>
  }, this)
};
```

---

(2) *In a separate method:*

```
{
  Object.keys(this.props.data).map(this.listItems.bind(this))
};
```

and add `listItems` method to your class:

```
listItems(key, index) {
  return <li key={index}>{this.props.data[index]}</li>
}
```

---

Comment: Correct, except `this` would not refer to any class, but to an instance of a class. I prefer the broader term "instance of react component", because not all react components are classes. (I accidentally proposed an edit to your answer when meaning to add this comment from my phone, I'm sorry :-( )

Answer (score 3):

@Basim already gave the correct answer. If you are using ES6, you can also do like this.

```
{Object.keys(this.props.data).map((key,index)=> {
        return <li key={index}>{this.props.data[key]}</li>
  })};
```